# HQL compare dates without microseconds

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, hql

I have query:

```
entityManager.createQuery("from Example where created > :since", Example.class);
```

App queries by: 2017-09-11T15:09:26.708Z

DB contains: 2017-09-11 15:09:26.708086

So I get an object which contains '2017-09-11 15:09:26.708086' which I expect 
to be absent.

How to trim microseconds in the query?

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: When you persist the DateTime in the DB, do you need the microseconds? When i work in MySQL, I can choose if I want the microseconds. I don't know if that could be chosen in PostgreSQL.